# Removing lines from a file that don't match a pattern using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to remove all the lines from a file that *don't* have the form:

> something.something,something,something

For example if the file was the following:

```
A sentence, some words  
ABCD.CP3,GHD,HDID  
Hello. How are you?  
A.B,C,D  
dbibb.yes,whoami,words
```

I would be left with:

```
ABCD.CP3,GHD,HDID  
A.B,C,D  
dbibb.yes,whoami,words
```

I have tried to branch to the end of the sed script if I match the pattern I don't want to delete but continue and delete the line if it doesn't match:

```
cp $file{,.tmp}
sed "/^.+\..+,.+,.+$/b; /.+/d" "$file.tmp" > $file
rm "$file.tmp"
```

but this doesn't seem to have any affect at all.

I suppose I could read the file line by line, check if matches the pattern, and output it to a file if it does, but I'd like to do it using sed or similar.

Comment: It's working in [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hO5rO8/1)

Comment: You could use grep -v

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `grep` successfully:

```
grep -E '^[^.]+\.[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+$' file > temp
mv temp file
```

Comment: This is the solution I have used. I was focused too much on using sed to think of using grep. Simple and it works, thanks.

Comment: grep is simpler but for inline edit it would be better if you prefer sed.

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -E '^[^.]+\.[^.]+(,[^,]+){2}$'
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of deleting the lines which didn't satisfies the pattern, you could  print the lines that matches this `something.something,something,something` pattern.

### Through sed,

```
$ sed -n '/^[^.]*\.[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,.]*$/p' file
ABCD.CP3,GHD,HDID  
A.B,C,D  
dbibb.yes,whoami,words
```

Use inline edit option `-i[suffix]` to save the changes made.

```
sed -ni.bak '/^[^.]*\.[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,.]*$/p' file
```

**Note:** `-i[suffix]` make a backup if `suffix` is provided.

### Through awk,

```
$ awk '/^[^.]*\.[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,.]*$/{print}' file
ABCD.CP3,GHD,HDID  
A.B,C,D  
dbibb.yes,whoami,words
```